# onclick even after loading a map - ammap

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I am using a small script I modified that uses ammaps library. I use the world map and if I click on certain countries it will load the country's map including the states.

Now, I am struggling on finding a solution to that after I opened a country and click on a state I want to use an onclick event then to just open up the appropriate website for that state. My jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/xzAx7/ and I would appreciate any help.

This is my code how I load new maps after I clicked on the country. These maps include the states.

```
    map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (event) {
        if (event.mapObject.id == "FR") {
            loadNewMap("http://www.ammap.com/lib/maps/js/franceLow.js", "franceLow");
        }
        else if (event.mapObject.id == "RU") {
            loadNewMap("http://www.ammap.com/lib/maps/js/russiaLow.js", "russiaLow");
        }
        else if (event.mapObject.id == "US") {
            loadNewMap("http://www.ammap.com/lib/maps/js/usaLow.js", "usaLow");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would move the handler to a separate function and would add another if, which would also check the id and generate url.

If you can not generate URL's automatically, then you should not use getAreasFromMap option but add each area in new data provider and set url property for the areas.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (event.mapObject.id == "FR") {
    map.clear();
    map.dataProvider.mapVar = AmCharts.maps.franceLow;
    map.write("mapdiv");
};
```

Comment: Please elaborate on why this answers the question and solve the OP issue.